# Prevent flickering while hovering CSS transform

Tags: css, css-transforms

While hovering the vertically rotating anchor if the mouse is not near the center of the image the animated transform flickers using the following code:

```
@keyframes spin {0% {transform: rotateX(0deg);} 100% {transform: rotateX(360deg);}}
a:focus, a:hover {animation: spin 0.9s 1 linear;}
```

How do I prevent the flickering without changing the HTML?

https://jsfiddle.net/jabcreations/ahcx0wfv/

Comment: Try to give some `padding-top` on `ul a` and check.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

To avoid getting `:hover` out of `a` and flickering you might move `:hover` from `a` to its parent:

```css
@keyframes spin {
  100% {
    transform: rotateX(360deg);
  }
}

ul {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  align-items: flex-start;
}

li:hover {
  cursor: pointer;
}

a:focus,
li:hover a {
  animation: spin 0.9s 1 linear;
}

ul a {
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
}

ul a:focus,
ul li:hover a {
  background-image: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #777 0%, #222 100%);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="admin/">Admin</a></li>
  <li><a href="appointments/">Appointments</a></li>
  <li><a href="blog/">Blog</a></li>
  <li><a href="calendar/">Calendar</a></li>
  <li><a href="contact/">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="events/">Events</a></li>
  <li><a href="forms/">Forms</a></li>
  <li><a href="forums/">Forums</a></li>
  <li><a href="guestbook/">Guestbook</a></li>
  <li><a href="mail/">Mail</a></li>
  <li><a href="members/">Members</a></li>
  <li><a href="newsletter/">Newsletter</a></li>
  <li><a href="notifications/">Notifications</a></li>
  <li><a href="search/">Search</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Worked though that will only work with two elements; the menus will work though not anchors inside of paragraphs in example. There are other CSS animations that can be done and the question will come down to consistency. I did post the HTML with the `li` elements so technically you didn't change the HTML so I've accepted it as the answer. The only way to improve it would be to be able to do this with an anchor inside of a paragraph while *still* not having the flickering or adding another element. Thank you very much!

Answer (score 1):

An idea without changing the html is to move the animation to a pseudo element and you will avoid the lose of the hover since the main element won't rotate:

You can also simplify your logic using transition instead of animation:

```css
p a {
  color: #000;
  display: inline-block;
  height: 50px;
  z-index:0;
  position:relative;
  color:transparent;
}
p a:before {
  content:attr(data-text);
  position:absolute;
  z-index:-1;
  top:0;
  left:0;
  right:0;
  bottom:0;
  color:#000;
  transition:transform 0.9s linear;
}
p a:focus::before,
p a:hover::before {
  transform: rotateX(360deg);
  background: radial-gradient(ellipse at center, #777 0%, #222 100%);
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<p>some content here <a href="admin/" data-text="Admin">Admin</a> and more here</p>
```